# Does res/raw or assets get updated when I publish update to Playstore?

Tags: android

I have a json file stored in res/raw in my Android app that I'd like to update every time I publish an update to the playstore. Does that file get updated every time I push to the playstore? I'm asking this because when I change/modify a res/raw or assets file while debugging it doesn't show a change, and I have to uninstall and reinstall the app for the change to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes res folder will be updated with updating app on google play store.If your case is frequently update raw file it is better to copy that file to internal or external storage.

Comment: Why is better to copy that file to another storage? I cache the contents of that file (size smaller than 1MB) when the app is first opened.

Comment: Apk contains resource folder, everything in apk is read only if you want to change frequently raw file every time you need to upload apk, so it is better to copy that file into storage and you can also change it using download file from your server easily.

Comment: Fair enough; if I don't want to edit the file and keep it as a ready only I suppose this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: What about the contents in the assets folder? I suppose the assets\databases db files are not updated since the db files contain user data, but what about the other files in the assets folder?